# Error while deploying Uberfire webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, errai

I am using Jboss 7.1 to deploy the uberfire webapp project. To start with using Uberfire. I am able to build the war using the uberfire showcase source code, while trying to deploy the same on jboss am getting the below error. Please help me get around this if any one has any suggestions/solution.

> "},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.uberfire-webapp.uberfire-webapp.env.ErraiService
>   jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.ErraiServiceMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.uberfire-webapp.uberfire-webapp.env.ErraiServicejboss.n
>   aming.context.java.jboss.resources.ErraiService]"]}}}

Comment: Are you building the master branch or the tags? Can you check whether you are getting the same error on the latest 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT? The pre-built war is linked from [here](http://www.uberfireframework.org/quick-start.html#_get_the_pre_built_war_file)

Comment: I dont wanna struggle with unstable version, hence i took version 5.x. I took it from the below branch. https://github.com/uberfire/uberfire/tree/0.5.x. I had many other roadblocks, when i tried with the master branch.

Comment: Version 5.x - this is the branch. Please get the tag from [here](https://github.com/uberfire/uberfire/releases/tag/0.5.0.20140419-M1). Please let me know the results of the pre-built war deployment.

And you may face issues with version 5 as well as version 6. 4 is far stable then those versions. You can try the latest tags of all versions [here](https://github.com/uberfire/uberfire/releases)

Comment: The tag that you have mentioned here is also not working. From where do i get the stable tag the version 6.4 that you are referring to ?